# RecyclerView scrolling shadow

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a scrolling sheet of paper containing a RecyclerView. To achieve this I gave each item a background and its own shadow. When you look closely you can see where the items meet because the shadow is slightly darker. The left list also has a divider which has the wrong color because the shadow is behind it.

I was wondering if there may be a better solution for this. You can't set the background and shadow on the RecyclerView itself because then it wouldn't scroll of the screen as the bounds don't change. You can't use a LinearLayout+ScrollView because this would break when there are too many items.

[image: Artifacts where the shadows meet]

Answer (score 0):

I would say just use CardView and set `useCompatPadding` to true in your XML so that it adds enough padding for the shadows not to overlap.

Alternatively, you can add margin to your items.

Another option is using an ItemDecorator that does not draw anything but returns enough margin for shadows in the `getItemOffsets` method.

Comment: That's not the effect that I'm after. I want all the list items to appear on the same sheet of paper. Much like Google Now shows the weather of multiple locations on a single card.

Comment: Sorry i got the question wrong. For grouping items, there is no built in solution. If items per card is not too many, just add them in to the adapter as 1 item that contains all and use CardView to display them. 
If items per card may grow a lot, then you can do it by having different view types for top, bottom and middle and some custom drawables for shadows. Sorry, there is no built in way for this.